# PHP Text to display is interpreted as part of array

Tags: php, notice

I have this code:

```
return t("Use tokens like: eg. [youtube_video:id]");
```

Because of the brackets used in my string PHP treat this [youtube_video:id] **as an array key** and returns notice like: Notice: Use of undefined constant _miscellaneous_filter_tips - assumed '_miscellaneous_filter_tips' w miscellaneous_filter_info_alter()

How can I resolve it?

All the code after a request:

```
function _miscellaneous_filter_tips() {
    return t('Use tokens like: eg. [yamandi:youtube_video:id]');
}

function miscellaneous_filter_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['filter_tokens']['tips callback'] = _miscellaneous_filter_tips;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I've already tried it

Comment: it's a function to translate

Comment: Looks like this notice tells you about different problem ... Show the source of t()

Comment: but when I remove this part of text the problem disappears

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7

But even if I remove this t() function notice is displaying

Answer (score 0):

since I don't have the precursor code I can't actually see what the function t() does, however if is seems to think you are calling a variable try using

```
return t('Use tokens like: eg. [youtube_video:id]');
```

or if you still want to use variables

```
return t("Use tokens like: eg. " . '[youtube_video:id]');
```

Comment: it's still the same notice :|

Comment: It doesn't make much sense then, as single quotes it shouldn't attempt to parse any variables

Answer (score 0):

Just change the double quote into a single quote:

```
return t('Use tokens like: eg. [youtube_video:id]');
```

**EDIT**

After looking to the updated code, this might be a completely different issue, I think you might wanna try this way of storing function hooks:

```
function _miscellaneous_filter_tips() {
    return t('Use tokens like: eg. [yamandi:youtube_video:id]');
}

function miscellaneous_filter_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['filter_tokens']['tips callback'] = '_miscellaneous_filter_tips';
}
```

And then when you want to call that function, you can simply use:

```
$info['filter_tokens']['tips callback']();
```

Comment: I've already tried it. Even after removing this t() function notice is displaying.

Comment: This example will tell you that there is nothing wrong with this string: http://codepad.org/2Bb0l9Z2, you might be having the error because of something else, would you share more code?

Comment: I've updated my question and added all the code I have. Maybe this is  happen because this miscellaneous_filter_info_alter function is a hook of different function/functions?